# Calculated Model Sum

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

Currently, the [Calculated Model Sample app](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/calculated-model/) only calculates the *count* of the records for each **Type**. I would like to calculate the *sum* of the ratings for each **Type** as well.

To briefly explain the app's data model, there are three fields for each record: Name (str), **Type** (str), and **Rating** (num).

I have added a *sum* *field* to the **Aggregation** calculated model, but am unclear what exactly I need to change in the code **CalculatedModels** script in the app.

Here is the code block which calculates the *count* of each **Type**. I've added the `records.Sum =` to indicate how and where the *sum* should be recorded. However, since the existing for loop increments by 1 (to calculate the *count*), do I need another for loop that would increment by the value of each record's **Rating** (since the *sum* will be the total of the **Ratings** for each **Type**? Or can I just use the existing for loop, as I have indicated by inserting the `records.Sum =` where I did?

```
/**
 * Gathers statistics of Data records distribution by Type field values.
 * Used by the calculated datasource AggregationByType.
 * @return {Array<Aggregation>} array of records with the stats by Type.
 */  

function getStatisticsByType_() {
      var allRecords = app.models.Data.newQuery().run();
      var stats = {};
      for (var i = 0; i < allRecords.length; i++) {
        var recordType = allRecords[i].Type;
        if (!stats[recordType]) {
          stats[recordType] = 0;
        }
        stats[recordType]++;
      }

  var records = [];
  var properties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(stats);
  for (var j = 0; j < properties.length; j++) {
    var record = app.models.Aggregation.newRecord();
    record.Name = properties[j];
    record.Count = stats[properties[j]];
    record.Sum = 
    records.push(record);
  }
  records.sort(sortDataByName_);
  return records;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. Sorry don't have the time to explain at the moment.

```
function getStatisticsByType_() {
  var allRecords = app.models.Data.newQuery().run();
  var stats = {};
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < allRecords.length; i++) {
    var recordType = allRecords[i].Type;
    var num = allRecords[i].Rating;
    if (!stats[recordType]) {
      stats[recordType] = {'Count': 0, 'Sum': 0};
    }
    stats[recordType].Count++;
    stats[recordType].Sum += num;
  }

  var records = [];
  var properties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(stats);
  console.log(stats);
  for (var j = 0; j < properties.length; j++) {
    var record = app.models.Aggregation.newRecord();
    record.Name = properties[j];
    record.Count = stats[properties[j]].Count;
    record.Sum = stats[properties[j]].Sum;
    records.push(record);
  }
  records.sort(sortDataByName_);
  return records;
}
```